# What happens to Wesley Crusher when he leaves with the Traveler?

Tags: character, star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

In the television episode [Journey's End](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey%27s_End_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29) of Star Trek: The Next Generation, Wesley Crusher leaves the Enterprise, drops out of Star Fleet Academy and joins the Traveler. This is the last episode where Wesley makes an appearance on the show.

Has there ever been any clarification of what happens to Wesley? Where he goes with the Traveler and what he learns. Wikipedia states he makes an appearance in Star Trek Nemesis, but it seems like his character's plot is just ignored.

Comment: He went to become Sheldon Cooper's arch nemesis

Comment: In Picard Season 2, Wesley Crusher came to Earth to recruit Kore Soong into the Travelers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

More details than you could possibly want are available at [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Wesley_Crusher).

> In 2370, cadet Crusher resigned from Starfleet Academy after The
>   Traveler - posing as a villager on Dorvan V - guided him through a
>   vision of his deceased father who told him that his destiny lay
>   somewhere other than with Starfleet and that he should not follow in
>   his footsteps. Much to his mother's and Picard's disappointment yet
>   with their support, Wesley heeded the advice after which The Traveler
>   revealed his true identity and promised to mentor the young man on his
>   new journey, presumably to other planes of existence.

And

> Crusher eventually returned to Starfleet and in 2379 he became a
>   full-fledged officer, holding the rank of Lieutenant Junior Grade.

I don't believe that there are significant details about what he actually does with The Traveler.

Comment: Additional: The deleted scene in Star Trek Nemesis http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACQqe5-B3TI

Comment: So there really is no answer to the question, and he was basically removed from the show. Understandably, he wasn't my fav character, but it would be interesting to know if there are any books that explore what happen.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini [you can read wil wheatons book "just a geek"](http://www.amazon.com/Just-Geek-Wil-Wheaton/dp/059600768X)

Answer (score 13):

From [**Memory Beta**](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Wesley_Crusher), the database for all licensed Star Trek works *(including e.g. novels, comic books, video games,...)*:

> - in 2373 Wesley altered history by erasing the *Maquis*, and instead created a short border war between the *Federation* and the *Cardassian Union*. 
>   (***Short Story:*** [***Gods, Fate and Fractals***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Gods,_Fate,_and_Fractals))
> - Around the end of the *Dominion War*, Wesley encountered [J. R. Rasmussen](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/J._R._Rasmussen), a time-traveling researcher for 20th century television program, *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*. 
>   (***Short Story:*** [***Research***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Research))
> - In 2377, Wesley briefly boarded the *USS Enterprise-E* under the guise of [Evan Jackson](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Evan_Jackson). 
>   (***Short Story:*** [***Adventures in Jazz and Time***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Adventures_in_Jazz_and_Time))
> - In 2378, Wesley gave advice and assistance to Starfleet *Captain Chakotay* when Chakotay temporarily possessed the power of the *Sky Spirits*. 
>   (***Novel:*** [Enemy of my Enemy](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_of_My_Enemy))
> - Later in 2378, Wesley had learned a lot from The Traveler and [...] they returned to Tau Alpha C so that Wesley could be re-born as a Traveler. 
>     
>   Before becoming a Traveler, Wesley had to gaze into the [Pool of Prophecy](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Pool_of_Prophecy) to undergo the final test. Inside the Pool, he witnessed the destruction of the *Enterprise* at the [Rashanar Battle Site](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Rashanar_Battle_Site). 
>   Following this, he left Tau Alpha C and went to the *Enterprise* to successfully prevent their destruction from a shape-shifting vessel from another dimension. 
>   (***Novels:*** [***A Time to Be Born***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/A_Time_to_Be_Born) and [***A Time to Die***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/A_Time_to_Die))
> - In late 2379, Wesley appeared at the wedding of *William Riker* and *Deanna Troi*. 
>     
>    In 2381, Wesley materialized at the wedding of his mother, *Beverly Crusher*, and *Jean Luc Picard*. 
>     
>   (***Novels:*** [***A Time for War, A Time for Peace***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/A_Time_for_War,_A_Time_for_Peace) and [***Greater Than the Sum***](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_Than_the_Sum))

(*Novels* and *Short Stories* are usually not considered [*canon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon))

Comment: Interesting. I always found the idea of him becoming a Traveler sort of non-trek, and reminds me a lot of the ancients in Stargate. This sort of thought/energy evolved state of humans is kind of like hippy scifi to me.

Comment: It baffles me that writers think a young genius will still be recognizable after a decade apprenticed to a being who can alter time and space with its mind. Your teenage kid can completely re-imagine their own identity after a single day at Burning Man, but three tours-of-duty with The Traveler and all Wesley has to show for it is that he parts his hair on the other side.